# Modify the value of all elements of an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to change the value of all elements of an array list

```
    if (country.hostel) {
        country.hostel.forEach(function (hostel, index) {
            hostel.room.forEach(function (room, index) {
                room = {code:{value: BOOKED}};
            });
        });
    }
```

but I have a warning in the code as if the room value will not change

```
The value assigned is never used
```

Comment: 'The value assigned is never used ' : This basically means that the value isn't used and nothing else. Please explain what exactly is failing.

Comment: To modify a specific key in an array you'd need to refer to it as: `Array[index] = YOUR_VALUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
(country.hostel || []).forEach(hostel => hostel.room.forEach((room) => {
  room.code.value = BOOKED
}));
```

```js
const country = {
  hostel: [
    {
      room: [
        { code: { value: 'AAAAA' } },
        { code: { value: 'AAAAA' } },
        { code: { value: 'AAAAA' } }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
const BOOKED = 'BOOKED';

(country.hostel || []).forEach(hostel => hostel.room.forEach((room) => {
  room.code.value = BOOKED
}));

console.log(country);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to address the element of the array for assigning.

```
if (country.hostel) {
    country.hostel.forEach(function (hostel) {
        hostel.room.forEach(function (room, index, array) {
            array[index] = { code: { value: BOOKED } };
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `map` function:

```
if (country.hostel) {
    country.hostel.forEach(function (hostel, index) {
        hostel.room = hostel.room.map(({room}) => ({
            room = {code:{value: BOOKED}};
        }));
    });
}
```

Comment: btw, a (destrucured) variable has no relation to the outer object anymore. and `map` makes no sense without using the result of it.